# Old DS.Model properties are present when creating a new model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a `DS.Model` with some nested keys:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  slug: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  config: DS.attr('', {
    defaultValue: {
      url: '',
      connections: 5,
      request_timeout: 2000,
      etc...
    }
  })
  ...
})
```

And a `new` route that creates a model for passing to a form:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('resource');
  },
  ...
```

After creating a new model via the form at `/resource/new`, on revisiting the form the `config` is still set to the values of the last created model.

I can see via [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) that the model is a different instance (having stored a reference to `oldModel` before leaving the page on the initial create):

```
oldModel.toString()
"<web@model:app::ember731:null>"
oldModel.get('config.url')
"http://localhost:4000/old"

newModel = $E
newModel.toString()
"<web@model:app::ember894:null>"
newModel.get('config.url')
"http://localhost:4000/old"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to the fact that `model.config` is shared among all of your model instances, since it's created at extend time and not at create time of each model instance. This is a JavaScript concept, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/483616) for more information.

You want each model to have it's own instance of `config`:

```
config: DS.attr({
  defaultValue() {
    return {
      url: '',
      connections: 5,
      request_timeout: 2000,
      //etc...
    };
  }
})
```

Also, one thing to keep in mind is that since `config` is a POJO, you will not have binding if you try to create observers or computed properties based on attributes within `config`.

I suggest using one of the following alternatives:

- https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments
- http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html embedding models (which would require a unique id for each config -- uuid)